# aws Lightsail Connexion refused by server

Tags: amazon-lightsail

i used my lightsail since more than one month, and this morning i got an issue from putty :connexion refused ,

i tried to connect using AWS web terminal and got message:
**An error occurred and we were unable to connect or stay connected to your instance. If this instance has just started up, try again in a minute or two.
UPSTREAM_NOT_FOUND **

My 22 port already opened and i dont have backup,
i still have ftp access and i have plesk  working too

-i already  rebooted the instance

-stopped then start the instance

-i checked the security group , port 22 is openned

Comment: did you have any success here?

Comment: I just started having this problem tonight with a Lightsail instance. And sure enough, no support for Basic accounts, so no way to get support on this.